# Select from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I'm trying to select from a sub-query to limit the group_concat function here whats I'm using

```
SELECT 

GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
`comment_content`,' , ',
    (SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)  FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = t1.`uid` LIMIT 1)
) SEPARATOR " | " )


FROM  `posts_comments`t1  WHERE `pid` = 324 LIMIT 4
```

the above query is working fine but it's not limiting the result so what I'm trying is this

```
SELECT 

GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
`comment_content`,' , ',
    (SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)  FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = t1.`uid` LIMIT 1)
) SEPARATOR " | " )


FROM ( SELECT * FROM  `posts_comments`   WHERE `pid` = 324 ORDER BY `comment_date` DESC LIMIT 4 ) t1
```

to select from a sub-query result but I'm getting this error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 10

I'm trying to figure this out but no luck why am I getting this error when I'm trying to select from a sub-query?

**UPDATE 1**

the problem comes from this

> (SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)  FROM `users` WHERE
>   `uid` = t1.`uid` LIMIT 1)

becuse it's selecting from another table when i join the user table and select locally it's wroking fine

Comment: need an order by on your limit for it to make sense.  or will any 4 records due each time?  why would there ever be more than 1 line?  Explain you requirements  are you trying to get the first/last name of the X 4 users?  what is x?  most recent? any? by last name? those with the most recent or oldest posts?

Comment: i added the order,,

Comment: i don't see limit 0,25 in your query ...  ??????

Comment: @scaisEdge will me too ,,, i dont know why it outputs 0,25 im using phpmyadmin

Comment: Have you tried running the query from a command line rather than phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Go the other direction:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(..., name, ...))
    FROM (
        SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ', last) AS name
            FROM posts_comments
            JOIN users ON ...
            WHERE ...
         ) AS x
```

But start by getting the subquery ("derived") to generate the 4 names in a column. *Then* put inside the `FROM` like above.